# How to pass choices in template using dropdown html fields? (Django)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

These are my files:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Campaign
from .forms import CampaignForm
from users.models import CustomUser
def create(request):

    form = CampaignForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title']
        types = request.POST['type']
        category = request.POST['category']
        location = request.POST['location']
        funding_goal = request.POST['funding_goal']


        user = CustomUser.objects.first()

        campaign = Campaign.objects.create(
            title =         title,
            types =         types,
            category =      category,
            location =      location,
            funding_goal =  funding_goal,
            starter =       user
        )

        return redirect('campaign:campaign_list')

    return render(request, 'create_a_campaign.html', {'formset':form})
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Campaign

class CampaignForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Campaign
       fields = ['title','types','category','location','funding_goal']
```

**Models.py**

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    types = (
        ('health', 'Health'),
        ('education', 'Education'),
    )

    categories = (
        ('health', 'Health'),
        ('education', 'Education'),
    )

    locations = (
        ('karachi','Karachi'),
        ('lahore','Lahore'),
        ('islamabad','Islamabad'),
        ('quetta','Quetta'),
        ('peshawar','Peshawar'),
    )

    title =          models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description =    models.CharField(max_length=700, null=True, blank=True)
    types =          models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=types, null=True, blank=True)
    category =       models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=categories, null=True, blank=True)
    tags =           TaggableManager(blank=True)
    image =          models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    location =       models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=locations, null=True, blank=True)
    funding_goal =   models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
    starter =        models.ForeignKey(user.CustomUser, related_name='campaigns', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    last_updated =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    team =           models.OneToOneField(Team, related_name='campaigns', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    shop =           models.OneToOneField(shop_models.Shop, related_name='campaigns', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Html template**

```
<div class="field-select field-cat">
    <select name="type" id="field-cat">
        <option value="">Select type</option>
               {% for type in formset.types %}
        <option value="{{ type }}"></option>
               {% endfor %}
```

Whenever I save the instance, it saves the type as "option value=" in type column. How do I pass type in database properly?

Comment: Please copy the code in code snippets, because we cannot copy the content of images in our editors except by typing everything over manually.

Comment: Edited the question.